# Custom hotkey/shortcut to open/bring to front an app

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, dbus

I don't imagine this is built into the system, but is it possible to do it without too much hassle?

Say I open a specific program with a hotkey, and when I press that hotkey again, the program window is brought to the front.

I want to do this on Ubuntu 9.04.

Maybe with D-Bus? Any experts?

**Update**: Here's what I ended up with in case it's of help to somebody:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f "/tmp/myterm.pid" ]; then
  WID=`cat /tmp/myterm.pid`
  xdotool windowactivate $WID
  if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
    WID=""
  fi
else
  WID=`xdotool search --title "UNIQUE TITLE" | head -1`
fi

if [ "$WID" == "" ]; then
  /usr/bin/gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=MYPROFILE "$@"
  WID=`xdotool search --title "UNIQUE TITLE" | head -1`
  echo $WID > /tmp/myterm.pid
else
  xdotool windowactivate $WID
fi
```

Surely it can be simplified, but I'm no `bash` wiz. Also, for my example to work, I created a custom profile in Terminal that applies a unique title to the window so it can be found later. The possibilities are endless!

Comment: For this simple task, jtb's method works better, because xdotools sometimes throws X errors, and wmctrl is faster.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `wmctrl` program is just what you're looking for (`sudo apt-get install wmctrl`). You can use the `wmctrl -a "AppTitle"` command to bring the app to the front. `wmctrl -l` will list all available windows, so it should be easy to write a shell script that checks if your program is running and either launches it or brings it to the front. Then you can just bind that to a keyboard shortcut.

First save the following script somewhere, I'll use `/home/jtb/code/bringToFront`. It takes two arguments, the first is what you would type at the terminal to launch the program, the second is a substring of the program window's title. If there is no constant unique string in the title then you'll need to do a bit more work to find the program's window.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `wmctrl -l | grep -c "$2"` != 0 ]  
then
    wmctrl -a "$2"
else
    $1 &
fi
```

2. With the script in your current directory, run `chmod +x bringToFront` to make the script executable. Then make sure it works; to launch/focus firefox you could run `./bringToFront firefox "Mozilla Firefox"`.
3. Now we need to bind a shortcut key. Run `gconf-editor` and navigate the folder structure to the left to `/apps/metacity/keybinding_commands`.
4. Double click on the first `command` with a blank value, probably `command_1`. Type the full path to the script and provide the two parameters, e.g. `/home/jtb/code/bringToFront firefox Firefox`.
5. From the panel on the left, select `global_keybindings`, the next folder up. Find the `run` entry matching the command you just defined, probably `run_command_1`. Double click it and type the keyboard shortcut you want to use. Put the modifiers in angle brackets, e.g. `<Ctrl><Alt>F`.

Now <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> will bring your firefox window to the front, or launch it if it's not already running.

Comment: Yeah, I found out about that a couple of minutes ago, but I went with xdotool. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention I also used the global shortcuts and commands in gconf to fully accomplish the effect (a poor man's Quake console!).

Comment: Ah, yeah I haven't used xdotool myself but it looks like it would give you some more flexibility. Good point about gconf. Since that's pretty non-obvious I might as well edit the answer to include more details for anybody else looking to do this.

Comment: Poort Man's Quake console? You mean like Tilda? http://freshmeat.net/projects/tilda

Comment: Yes, I use Tilda too, but I work on several projects through the week, and for each one I always open three or four tabs, so quickly switching to the project's console ("workspace") without cluttering Tilda is very useful for me.

Comment: Sweet.  Love this.  Went looking for something like it to replace Guake - I wanted this functionality without losing all my window decorations.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do it with `xdotools`. The process to pop-up is recognized by the command line issued to run it (no pid file or unique window title needed).

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="$@"
# command line to be run. Note that the resulting
# process will hold this in /proc/PID/cmdline 

pid=`pgrep -nf "^$cmd$"`
# most recent process having "$cmd" in /proc/PID/cmdline

if [ -z "$pid" ]; then # no pid
    exec $cmd
    # run command
else
    winid=`xdotool search --all --pid $pid --onlyvisible | head -1`
    # first visible window owned by pid
    xdotool windowactivate $winid
    # give window focus
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and since I didn't find any suiting solution, I made one :

https://hyperkeys.xureilab.com

https://github.com/xurei/hyperkeys

You can pin a window with a shortcut you define. I personally use SHIFT+ALT+[QWER] to pin and ALT+[QWER] to bring to front. You can't open the app if it's not open, though.

This is an open-source, linux-first tool. A Windows version is also available.

Hope it helps ! I'm looking for feedback, so if you have any question, create an issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I use a modified version of it to create a window shortcut script which also supports cycling through multiple instances. If you are interested: [Window Shortcuts for Linux](http://somanov.wordpress.com/2009/12/02/window-shortcuts-for-linux-desktops/).

> The script makes use of the wmctrl utility which can easily be
> installed with
>
> ```
> sudo aptitude install wmctrl
> ```
>
> Here is the “focus” script:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> import os
> import sys
> import commands
>  
> program_name = sys.argv[1] # the program to be focused
>  
> # get all windows which contain "program_name" from wmcontrol
> candidates = sorted([x.strip() for x in commands.getoutput(""" wmctrl -l -x | awk -v win="%s" 'tolower($0) ~ win {print $1;}' """ % (program_name, )).split("\n") if x !=''])
>  
> if candidates : # at least one candidate found , we need to check if the active window is among the candidates (for cycling)
>  
>         # Get the id of the active window
>  
>         # Note: wmctrl currently does not support getting information about the active window.  In order to realize this
>         #       we use xprop here. Unfortunately xprop gives us the window id of the active window in a different format:
>         #       Window ids from wmctrl always begin with 0x followed by 8 digits (leading zeroes for padding). xprop
>         #       does not do the padding and might give a window id starting with 0x followed by only 6 digits. The
>         #       lines below get the id of the current window and make the id returned by xprop comaptible with
>         #       the window ids returned by wmctrl.
>         active_window_string = commands.getoutput("""xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)" """)
>         active_window_string =  active_window_string[active_window_string.find("#")+4:].strip()
>         active_window = "0x" + "0" * (8-len(active_window_string)) + active_window_string
>  
>         next_window = None # the window to display. (one of the windows in candidates)
>         if active_window not in candidates: # if the active window is not among the candidate windows
>                 next_window = candidates[0] # ..just show the first candidate window
>         else:# we are already showing one of the candidate windows
>                 next_window = candidates[ (candidates.index(active_window)+1) % len(candidates)] # show the *next* candidate in the list (cycling)
>  
>         if next_window:
>                 os.system(""" wmctrl -i -a "%s" """ % (next_window,) ) # tell wmcontrol to display the next_window
> else : # no windows open which fit the pattern of program_name
>     os.system("%s &" % (program_name,)) # open new window
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by [jtb](https://superuser.com/a/16651/266037) earlier is excellent but sometimes you'd want to match exact titles (e.g. you want to open "GitKraken" but your browser's title "GitKraken vs CLI" is also matching the query).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == "-exact" ]
then
    additional_arguments="-F "
    app_launch_command=$2
    app_title=$3
else
    additional_arguments=""
    app_launch_command=$1
    app_title=$2
fi

if [ `wmctrl -l $additional_arguments| grep -c "$app_title"` != 0 ]
then
    wmctrl $additional_arguments -a "$app_title"
else
    $app_launch_command &
fi
```

So now you can call your bringToFront script like following:

```bsh
#exact match
./bringToFront.sh -exact "flatpak run com.axosoft.GitKraken" "GitKraken"
#or
./bringToFront.sh -exact <command_to_launch_the_app> <app_title

#partial match like the old script
./bringToFront.sh "flatpak run com.axosoft.GitKraken" "GitKraken"
#or
./bringToFront.sh <command_to_launch_the_app> <app_title>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not parameterised, but I have used it to *bring-to-focus* or *start* the gnome-calculator.

The -R option finds the window or fails, if found it is moved to the current desktop, raised and given focused. The gnome-calculator names it's window with the name *Calculator*, it could easily be parameterised, but I have never found the need to do so. I have it mapped to `Ctrl-Alt-c`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# start the calculator and raise and focus (requires wmctrl)
# X Tian 06sep2017 created

wmctrl -R Calculator
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
  then 
    gnome-calculator &
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: This answer is specific to Linux Mint MATE (which is what I have) however it may point you in the right direction or give you ideas still.

---

On Mint you can do it without having to write scripts:

1. Open "Mint Menu" -> "Control Center".
2. Search for/open "Keyboard Shortcuts".
3. At the buttom click "Add".
4. "Browse applications..." > and select whatever application you want to switch to.
5. Modify "Command" field to be `wmctrl -a "<substring of app's title>"`. For example `wmctrl -a "Firefox"`.
6. "Keyboard Shortcut" window now has a new entry for that program. Double click it and assign shortcut.